# Como saber que objeto input perdió el foco

Tags: jquery

Tengo lo siguiente en html:

```
<input type="text" id ="a">
<input type="text" id ="b">
<input type="text" id ="c">
```

y en jquery:

```
$('#a, #b, #c').blur(function(){
    //acá ejecutar de acuerdo al objeto que perdió el foco
});
```

Como sé que objeto fué el que perdió el foco?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta con capturar en una variable el **id** del elemento dentro de la función. Luego puedes usar la variable para lo que necesites, en el ejemplo lo muestro en consola.

`$(this)` hace referencia al elemento con el que se está interactuando en el momento de perder el foco.

Con `.prop('id')` capturas el valor del atributo **id**.

```js
$('#a, #b, #c').blur(function(){
    //Capturar el id del elemento que pierde el foco
    let idElemento = $(this).prop('id');
    //Mostrar el id en consola
    console.log(idElemento);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id ="a">
<input type="text" id ="b">
<input type="text" id ="c">
```

Comment: Excelente, justo lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

El primer argumento que reciben la funciones manejadoras de eventos es un objeto tipo [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event), en cuya propiedad [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/target) se tiene:

> una referencia al objeto en el cual se lanzó el evento

```js
$('#a, #b, #c').blur( function(evento){
    console.log('id',evento.target.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id ="a">
<input type="text" id ="b">
<input type="text" id ="c">
```